# Resolvent of the operator

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-restriction

Consider the Laplace operator defined on the biggest possible subset of$L^{2}(R^{2})$:

$T= - \partial^{2}_{x} -\partial^{2}_{y}+x^{2}+y^{2}+ 2.i(x \frac{\partial}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial}{\partial x})$

Let $\alpha \not\in\sigma(T)$ and let $(T-\alpha I)^{-1}u(x,y)=f(x,y)$.

Now,  let $F$ be the Fourier transform $(\zeta,\eta)$. We have

$\Big[(\zeta^{2} +\eta^{2})-\partial^{2}_{\zeta} -\partial^{2}_{\eta}-2i(\eta \frac{\partial}{\partial \zeta}-\zeta\frac{\partial}{\partial \eta}) -\alpha I)\Big]\widehat{f}(\zeta,\eta)=\widehat{u}(\zeta,\eta)$

So, I need to calculate  the resolvent of this operator. Does anybody have any ideas how to complete this.

Comment: calculate the resolvent does that mean finding an expression for $(T-\alpha I)^{-1}$  ?

Comment: @ user1952009 yes